# How to transpose dataframe to calculate flag of whether value exists or not?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data fame which looks like this

```
Sno|UserID|TypeExp
1|JAS123|MOVIE
2|ASP123|GAMES
3|JAS123|CLOTHING
4|DPS123|MOVIE
5|DPS123|CLOTHING
6|ASP123|MEDICAL
7|JAS123|OTH
8|POQ133|MEDICAL
.......
10000|DPS123|OTH
```

UserID is the column identifying a user and TypeExp column define its expenditure type in that month ,Now I have some 5 different Expenditure possible i.e

> TypeExpList=[MOVIE,GAMES,CLOTHING,MEDICAL,OTH]

now i want to transpose it to a user level Data frame in which has a 0 or 1 binary variable storing the information weather or not the user "X" has done the above Type of Expenditure

for example in above snapshot DataFrame output should look like

```
User| TypeExpList         #Type list is this array corresponding entry's [MOVIE,GAMES,CLOTHING,MEDICAL,OTH]
JAS123 |[1,0,1,0,1]      #since user has done expenditure on Movie,CLOTHING,OTHER Category 
ASP123 |[0,1,0,1,0]       #since User expenditure on  GAMES & MEDICAL
DPS123 |[1,0,1,0,1]         #since user expenditure on  MOVIE,CLOTHING & OTHER
POQ133 |[0,0,0,1,0]        #since User Expenditure on MEDICAL only
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the input dataset of yours.

```
$ cat input.csv
Sno|UserID|TypeExp
1|JAS123|MOVIE
2|ASP123|GAMES
3|JAS123|CLOTHING
4|DPS123|MOVIE
5|DPS123|CLOTHING
6|ASP123|MEDICAL
7|JAS123|OTH
8|POQ133|MEDICAL
```

With that, you do `pivot` over `groupBy` on `UserID`.

```
val bins = spark
  .read
  .option("sep", "|")
  .option("header", true)
  .csv("input.csv")
  .groupBy("UserID")
  .pivot("TypeExp")
  .count
  .na
  .fill(0)
scala> bins.show
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|UserID|CLOTHING|GAMES|MEDICAL|MOVIE|OTH|
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|POQ133|       0|    0|      1|    0|  0|
|JAS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  1|
|DPS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  0|
|ASP123|       0|    1|      1|    0|  0|
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
```

You've got your `0`s and `1`s. The final trick is to use `array` over columns to build the proper output where positions denote the expenditure.

```
val solution = bins.select(
  $"UserID" as "User",
  array("MOVIE","GAMES","CLOTHING","MEDICAL","OTH") as "TypeExpList")
scala> solution.show
+------+---------------+
|  User|    TypeExpList|
+------+---------------+
|POQ133|[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
|JAS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]|
|DPS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]|
|ASP123|[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]|
+------+---------------+
```

---

Given that an expenditure can occur zero, one or more times, `count` over expenditures could give `0`, `1` or higher numbers.

You could use a UDF to binarize the values and make sure that only `0`s and `1`s are used.

```
val binarizer = udf { count: Long => if (count > 0) 1 else 0 }
val binaryCols = bins
  .columns
  .filterNot(_ == "UserID")
  .map(col)
  .map(c => binarizer(c) as c.toString)
val selectCols = ($"UserID" as "User") +: binaryCols
val solution = bins
  .select(selectCols: _*)
  .select(
    $"User",
    array("MOVIE","GAMES","CLOTHING","MEDICAL","OTH") as "TypeExpList")
scala> solution.show
+------+---------------+
|  User|    TypeExpList|
+------+---------------+
|POQ133|[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
|JAS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]|
|DPS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]|
|ASP123|[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]|
+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`crosstab` will do most of the job:

```
val table = df.stat.crosstab("UserID", "TypeExp")

+--------------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|UserID_TypeExp|CLOTHING|GAMES|MEDICAL|MOVIE|OTH|
+--------------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|        ASP123|       0|    1|      1|    0|  0|
|        DPS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  0|
|        JAS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  1|
|        POQ133|       0|    0|      1|    0|  0|
+--------------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
```

and can be nicely coupled with strongly typed API:

```
table.map(_.toSeq match {
  case Seq(id: String, cnts @ _*) => 
    (id, cnts.map(c => if(c != 0) 1 else 0))}).toDF("UserId", "TypeExp")

+------+---------------+
|UserId|        TypeExp|
+------+---------------+
|ASP123|[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]|
|DPS123|[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
|JAS123|[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]|
|POQ133|[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]|
+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in Scala but it should be somewhat similar in PySpark as well because it uses DSL. Pivot is available with Spark 1.6+

```
val pivotDf = df.groupBy($"userid").pivot("typeexp").agg(count($"typeexp") )

pivotDf.show
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|userid|CLOTHING|GAMES|MEDICAL|MOVIE|OTH|
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+
|DPS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  0|
|JAS123|       1|    0|      0|    1|  1|
|ASP123|       0|    1|      1|    0|  0|
|POQ133|       0|    0|      1|    0|  0|
+------+--------+-----+-------+-----+---+

pivotDf.selectExpr("userid", "array(movie, games, clothing, medical,oth) as  TypExpList")
       .show
+------+---------------+
|userid|     TypExpList|
+------+---------------+
|DPS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]|
|JAS123|[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]|
|ASP123|[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]|
|POQ133|[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
+------+---------------+
```